# Can't add more than one document in the cloud firestore collection

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to save records in the cloud firestore using flutter. The thing is that it only **adds one element and keeps updating its values** whenever I add a new one through the app.

Here is my code:

```
Future addInterventionToDB(String userId, String etat, String op, String iv) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("interventions")
        .doc(userId)
        .set({
      'etat': etat,
      'operateur': op,
      'intervention': iv,
      'userId': user!.uid
    });
  }
```

and here is the function used in the UI part!

```
  String etatLabel = "";
  String operateur = "";
  String intervention = "";

  addIntervention(String etatt, String op, String iv) async {
    String currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    if (currentUser != null) {
      DatabaseMethods().addInterventionToDB(currentUser, etatt, op, iv);
    }
  }
```

and here is the button where I did the call of the method:

```
onPressed: () async {
                    await addIntervention(etatLabel, operateur, intervention);                   
                  },
```

Noting that the values are extracted from chips (selected value of each chip).
I don't know what's wrong in here, tried updating the state of the variables each time a new selection takes place, but still having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you passed the `userId` as the doc id, it keeps on overwriting it.

Replace

```
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("interventions")
        .doc(userId)
        .set({
      'etat': etat,
      'operateur': op,
      'intervention': iv,
      'userId': user!.uid
    });
```

with

```
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("interventions")
        .add({
      'etat': etat,
      'operateur': op,
      'intervention': iv,
      'userId': user!.uid
    });
```

But in this case, it adds random doc id. So you cannot fetch with `userId`. But you are already adding the `userId` as a field inside the document with this line `'userId': user!.uid`. So you can fetch with that.

Hope it helps! Happy coding:)

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct but since you might be using the same UID the data is being overwritten in the collection. Refer to this [site](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/firestore-subcollections-in-flutter-b717c193a13a) for more insight about using firestore. Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are setting `.doc(userId).set({})` the data (read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)). What you have to do is let firebase auto-generate unique uids for every document added. Check out a modified version of your code

```
Future addInterventionToDB(String userId, String etat, String op, String iv) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("interventions")
        .doc()
        .set({
      'etat': etat,
      'operateur': op,
      'intervention': iv,
      'userId': user!.uid
    });
  }
```

to read the data of a particular userId,

```
final query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("interventions").where("userId", isEqualTo:user!.uid).get();
```